# How to change background image of body using redux framework in wordpress theme option?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, redux-framework

I want to change my background image using redux-framework.I have used following codes, but its not working.First is my redux-code and second in my css code.If there is any alternate method please mention.

```
 array(
             'name' => "Background parttern",
            'id' => "background_parttern",
            'std' => "pattern11",
            'type' => "image_select",
            'title'    => __('Homepage Layout', 'personalblog'), 
            'subtitle' => __('Select Your Background Pattern.', 'personalblog'),
            'options' => array(
                'pattern1' => $personalblog_admin_img_dir . 'patterns/pattern1.png',
                'pattern2' => $personalblog_admin_img_dir . 'patterns/pattern2.png',

                'pattern54' => $personalblog_admin_img_dir . 'patterns/pattern54.png'  
                ),
             'output'    => array('background-image' => 'body' ),
              ),
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url('image/patterns/pattern2.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for the reference :-

- **First is redux-code**

> ```
> array(
>             'name' => "Background parttern",
>             'id' => "background_parttern",
>             'std' => "pattern11",
>             'type' => "select_image",
>             'title'    => __('Homepage Layout', 'personalblog'), 
>             'subtitle' => __('Select Your Background Pattern.', 'personalblog'),
>             'options' => Array(
>             'pattern1' => 
>                      Array ( 'alt'  => 'pattern1',
>                              'img'  => get_template_directory_uri() . 'image/patterns/pattern1.png',),
>             'pattern2' => 
>                      Array ('alt'  => 'pattern2',
>                             'img'  =>get_template_directory_uri() . 'image/patterns/pattern2.png',
>                            )
>                 ),
>               'output'    => array('background-image' => 'body' ),
>         ),
> ```

- **css code**

> ```
> body {
>           font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
>           font-size: 14px;
>           background-image: url("<?php echo '' . $redux_Options_name['background_parttern']; ?>");
>           background-repeat: repeat;
>      }
> ```

I hope this will help you .